# Is there a way to define database file for table data range in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to define database file for data range in one table in PostgreSQL ? I need to move data between PostgreSQL database and thinking if I use database file for movement ( rather than using SQL statments ) it will be faster. Will file movement be faster than SQL insert queries and is this a good solution ?

Comment: The only way to put data into Postgres (or any other relational database) is through SQL. There is no such thing as a "file movement" that you can use. And what exactly do you mean with "*move data between PostgreSQL database*"? Between different servers? Between different databases on the same server?

Comment: "move data between PostgreSQL database" means between different servers ( different machines ).

Comment: Then use pg_dump / pg_restore

Comment: I'm trying to implement a consistent hashing with virtual nodes for PostgreSQL. That's why i need to move data between different servers. When node is added virtual node range is changed and new range's data should be moved to appropriate server. So portion of table should be moved to other server. Therefore can pg_dump / pg_restore used in such a scenario ?

Comment: Then maybe through a foreign data wrapper: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Answer (score 1):

Copying a full database with Postgres is not impossible, but copying per table will require smarter replication.

For copying the full database you can do something like this:

```
psql -c "select pg_start_backup('backup label', true);"
rsync -av --exclude pg_xlog --exclude postgresql.conf --exclude postgresql.pid data remote_server:data
psql -c 'select pg_stop_backup();'
```

Copying a part of a database is somewhat more complicated. For that there are several options available, previously Slony was the recommended option but that project is inactive these days. Right now your options are Foreign Data Wrappers, PL/Proxy or one of the options mentioned in the Postgres wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Replication,_Clustering,_and_Connection_Pooling#Clustering